# HBase shell giving ServerNotRunningYetException: Server is not running yet

Tags: hbase

I faced the following error while trying to access hbase shell. I installed Hadoop 3.3.1 and Hive, the hbase version is 2.4.15.

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ServerNotRunningYetException: Server is not running yet
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkServiceStarted(HMaster.java:2804)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.isMasterRunning(MasterRpcServices.java:1163)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:387)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:132)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:369)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:349)
```

when running jps I get

```
182002 HRegionServer
 243859 HMaster
 5698 DataNode
 243783 HQuorumPeer
 6551 NodeManager
 6376 ResourceManager
 5482 NameNode
 265023 Jps
 5932 SecondaryNameNode
```

the following is my hbase-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.master.port</name>
<value>60001</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/home/hdoop/hbase/zookeeper</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxns</name>
<value>35</value>
</property>
```

I tried to change the xml configuration but nothing helped

Comment: I also added this to hbase-site.xml  `<property>
  <name>hbase.wal.provider</name>
  <value>filesystem</value>
</property>`

Answer (score 0):

update: it worked after adding the below property

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.wal.provider</name>
  <value>filesystem</value>
</property>
```

which originally was a solution by @MrWrzosek. Check the link below for a detailed issue and answer:

[HBase Shell - org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ServerNotRunningYetException: Server is not running yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70523635/hbase-shell-org-apache-hadoop-hbase-ipc-servernotrunningyetexception-server-i)

***Note***: Make sure to stop the services and restart your machine after the changes.